# How can I reduce time complexity of my code?

Tags: python, list

So, the question is such that:
"Sum of the times there are duplicates in the list"

i.e
If Input: 1 2 3 1 4 1 5 6 2 9 8

Then, output should be (5) as 1 is three times and (2) is two times in the list and if there aren't any reoccurring elements in the list. The code should return -1.

My code is giving the desirable output but I want to improve the time complexity of the code as when I am running the code in an online compiler I am getting time complexity issue in some cases. I don't know what the cases are as they are hidden. I also used list comprehension here as I thought that would be better than using for loop but it doesn't did the trick for me. Can someone suggest me in what ways I can improve that in it? That would be very helpful.

PS: This is my first time asking a question here so I may have done some mistake. I would be grateful if you could address that too. Thank you in advance.

```
your_list = list(input().split())
dict_of_counts = {item:your_list.count(item) for item in your_list}
#print(dict_of_counts)
values = dict_of_counts.values()
k = list(values)
#print(k)
total = 0
j=[k[i] for i in range(0,len(k)) if k[i]>1]
y=[k[u] for u in range(0,len(k)) if k[u]<=1]
#print("j list is:" ,j)
#print("y list is:" ,y)
if len(y) == len(k):
     total = "-1"
for t in range(len(j)):
     total=total+j[t]
print(total)
```

Comment: Exemplary input and output, please

Comment: `dict_of_counts = {item:your_list.count(item) for item in your_list}` is straightway `O(n^2)` first fix this.

Comment: @tstanil I just edited the question. Hope that would help.

Comment: @Epsi95 The input list would be given by the user/computer itself by shape separated numbers. That's why I used  '''split()''' to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = input().split()
dict_of_counts = {}
for item in your_list:
    dict_of_counts[item] = dict_of_counts.get(item, 0) + 1
total = sum(val for val in dict_of_counts.values() if val > 1)
if total == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(total)
```

Or you may try:

```
your_list = input().split()
n = 0
for i in set(your_list):
    x = your_list.count(i)
    if x > 1:
        n += x
if n == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(n)
```

Comment: It is showing an error that ** not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) **on **  for key , val in dict_of_counts: **

Comment: @AdityaNegi yeah i forgot to use `items` function. Now it'll work. Also I've added another way to get the answer. That may be better.

Comment: I don't think declaring a set here would be the move as there can be value that can't be unique .

Comment: Actually, it'll work, first add all the numbers in your list... that includes unique ones as well, now substract the sum of all the unique numbers, there you get the sum of all duplicate numbers, now you have to merely multiply this result by 2. That's what I did. It works.

Comment: Yeah, that is working now @Nothing Special . Just also have to do total += val other than int(key)* val. Thanks alot mate.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question you din't want the sum rather how many  duplicates right?

Answer (score 0):

building dict_of_count has a complexity of O(n^2) because you are counting numbers for every position in the list.  You could reduce this a bit by using set(your_list) in the comprehension but that will still be O(n^2) in the worst case scenarios.

A more efficient approach would be to use the dictionary's O(1) indexing to count values in a loop.
This is what the Counter class from collections does:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 9, 8]
dupsum = sum(c for c in Counter(L).values() if c>1) or -1

print(dupsum) # 5
```

If you're not allowed to use libraries you can build the dictionary manually in a for loop:

```
counts = dict()
for n in L: counts[n] = counts.get(n,0) + 1
dupsum = sum(c for c in counts.values() if c>1) or -1
```

These solutions will produce results in O(n) time instead of O(n^2)

Another way to do it would be to build a list of the duplications using a set as a control mechanism and count items in that list:

```
dups   = [n for s in [set()] for n in L if n in s or s.add(n)]
dupsum = len(dups)+len(set(dups)) or -1
```

Comment: Thanks alot @ Alain T.  I didn't know this technique . It does improve the time complexity issue of my code and also made it smaller. Will be using it in future instances.